# Pgfplots: vertical bar char prints only labels at one bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to create a vertical bar charts with two bars in it. At the x-axis the bars shall be labeled with A and B.
The label A is printed although it is not exactly properly positioned, but the label B seems to be swallowed entirely by something. See my attachment.
Can someone tell me what I am missing?

[image]

Here is a MWE of my plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.4,
    symbolic x coords={A,B},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,7)};
\addplot coordinates {(B,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need `\addplot coordinates {(A,7)(B,4)};`

Comment: I want the two bars to have different colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[bar shift=0pt]` to overwrite the original bar with one of a different color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.4,
    symbolic x coords={A,B},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,7)(B,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(B,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar plot]